# jQuery only get clicked on elements data

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, element

I hope someone can help me with this issue

I've been working on creating buttons that when clicked it adds the data to a form
to be sent off.

As seen here:

```
<div>
  <li id="song-button">
        <h3 class="song">Song #1</h3>
        <div class="artist">Artist #1</div>
  </li>

  <li id="song-button">
        <h3 class="song">Song #2</h3>
        <div class="artist">Artist #2</div>
  </li>  
</div>

  <form>
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">
            <label>Artist: </label>
          </td>
            ................
```

Script Code:

```
$( "#song-button" ).click(function() {

    var artist = $(".artist").text();
    var song = $("h3").text();

    $("#artist-field").val(artist);
    $("#song-field").val(song);
});
```

Is there anyway to only get the **li** thats clicked on's data for the form?

Comment: Ids must be unique. Change it to class rather than id if you are not able to assign unique ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` should be unique for each element. Use `song-button` `class` instead of `id` like following.

```
<div>
    <li class="song-button">
        <h3 class="song">Song #1</h3>
        <div class="artist">Artist #1</div>
    </li>
    <li class="song-button">
        <h3 class="song">Song #2</h3>
        <div class="artist">Artist #2</div>
    </li>  
</div>
```

Use `find` to get data under clicked element.

```
$( ".song-button" ).click(function() {
    var artist = $(this).find(".artist").text();
    var song = $(this).find("h3").text();

    $("#artist-field").val(artist);
    $("#song-field").val(song);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you must change your selector with class , id is unique so i've changed your code a little ...

```
<div>
  <li class="song-button">
        <h3 class="song">Song #1</h3>
        <div class="artist">Artist #1</div>
  </li>

  <li class="song-button">
        <h3 class="song">Song #2</h3>
        <div class="artist">Artist #2</div>
  </li>  
</div>

  <form>
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">
            <label>Artist: </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
  </form>
```

and the script must changed like this

```
$( ".song-button" ).click(function() {

var artist = $(this).find('.artist').text();
var song = $(this).find('.song').text();

$("tbody tr").append('<td align="left"><label>Artist:'+artist+' </label></td>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Id must be unique. So me edited 'song-button' as class**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".song-button").click(function () {

            var artist = $(this).find('div.artist').text()
            var song = $(this).find('h3.song').text()

            alert(artist)
            alert(song)
        });


    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    song-button
    <div>
  <li class="song-button">
        <h3 class="song">Song #1</h3>
        <div class="artist">Artist #1</div>
  </li>

  <li class="song-button">
        <h3 class="song">Song #2</h3>
        <div class="artist">Artist #2</div>
  </li>  
</div>

</body>

</html>
```